# How to solve the issue "No package 'gtk+-2.0' 'glib-2.0' gthread-2.0 when compile packeteth on ubuntu20.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, configure

The packeth( version 1.6) can work on ubuntu20.04, but I want to upgrade to 2.0
1 I download new version of packeth:  http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/Home.html
2 it prompt errors as below:

```
.../packETH$ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
......
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.4 glib-2.0 >= 2.4 gthread-2.0 >= 2.4... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.4 glib-2.0 >= 2.4 gthread-2.0 >= 2.4) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'gthread-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DEPS_CFLAGS
and DEPS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried firing up your fav search engine and typing in "ubuntu install gtk+-2.0"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the missing dependencies:

```
$ apt search libgtk+ libglib
...
$ sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
```

I used `apt-file` to figure out that `gthread-2.0` is part of `libglib2.0-dev`.